# Number Wildcard in Where Clause

Tags: sql, regex, database, oracle

I'm trying to add a number wildcard to a query to look for a number in a specific position.  The query looks something like this:

```
SELECT SUBMITTER
  FROM BASE_ELEMENT
 WHERE SUBMITTER LIKE 'm_%';
```

The problem with this query is that it picks up everything that starts with "m" and has a character in the second position.  I need something that work like a Unix wildcard:

```
'm[0-9]*'
```

I want it to include m0, m1, m2, etc, but exclude ma, mb, mc, etc.

How would I accomplish this in Oracle 10g?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In 10G you have the [*wonder*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski) of [regular expressions](http://psoug.org/reference/regexp.html). So, your query could be:

```
select submitter
  from base_element
 where regexp_like(submitter, '^m[[:digit:]]')
```

`^` anchors the expression to the start of the line and `[[:digit:]]` matches to any digit.

Comment: Thanks for the references.  I wasn't aware of the function "regexp_like".  That solved my problem.

Comment: No problem @jmquigley; my only advice is to not rely on regular expressions if you can avoid it. They can get massively over-complicated extremely easily, though they're perfect for situations like this.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the REGEXP_LIKE function (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm).

Your case could be solved like this:

`select submitter from base_element where regexp_like( submitter, '^m[0-9]' );`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `regexp_like`:

```
where regexp_like(submitter, '^m\d')
```